# python nested lists/dictionaries and popping values

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-lists

Apologies in advance for this being such a newbie question. I'm just beginning to write python and i've been having some confusion around popping values from nested dictionaries/lists so i appreciate any help!

I have this sample json data:

```
{ "scans": [
   { "status": "completed", "starttime": "20150803T000000", "id":533},
   { "status": "completed", "starttime": "20150803T000000", "id":539}
] }
```

i'd like to pop the 'id' out of the "scans" key.

```
def listscans():
  response = requests.get(scansurl + "scans", headers=headers, verify=False)
  json_data = json.loads(response.text)
  print json.dumps(json_data['scans']['id'], indent=2)
```

doesnt seem to be working because the nested key/values are inside of a list. i.e.

```
>>> print json.dumps(json_data['scans']['id'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

can anyone point me in the right direction to get this to work? my longterm goal with this is to create a for-loop that places all of the id's into another dictionary or list that i can use for another function.

Comment: from your last comment it seems like you already have a pretty good idea of what needs to be done. Why not try to code it and show us your attempt?

Comment: figured i'd not blast this thread with a million failed examples of what i tried to keep things concise for future readers that have a similar issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`json_data['scans']` returns a list of dicts, you are trying to index the list using a str i.e `[]["id"]` which fails for obvious reasons so you need to use the index to get each subelement:

```
print json_data['scans'][0]['id'] # -> first dict
print json_data['scans'][1]['id'] # -> second dict
```

Or to see all the id's iterate over the list of dicts returned using `json_data["scans"]`:

```
for dct in json_data["scans"]:
    print(dct["id"])
```

To save append to a list:

```
all_ids = []
for dct in json_data["scans"]:
    all_ids.append(dct["id"])
```

Or use a list comp:

```
all_ids = [dct["id"] for dct in json_data["scans"]]
```

If there is a chance the key `id` might not be in every dict, use `in` to check before you access:

```
all_ids = [dct["id"] for dct in json_data["scans"] if "id" in dct]
```

Comment: perfect! i was missing the list indexing position after ['scans']. makes sense now. I am kind of confused on the second example though. the:     print(d["id"])    is d the index position? i thought you had to put index positions inside of brackets to pop values

Comment: @dobbs,  we are iterating over the list in the loop so each `d` is each actual `element/dict` from the list so we access the dict by the key `id` to get each value

Answer (score 0):

Here how can you iterate over the items and extract all ids:

```
json_data = ...
ids = []
for scan in json_data['scans']:
    id = scan.pop('id')
    # you can use get instead of pop
    # then your initial data would not be changed, 
    # but you'll still have the ids
    # id = scan.get('id')
    ids.append();
```

This approach will work too:

```
ids = [item.pop('id') for item in json_data['scans']]
```